# Do choices matter in Beyond: Two Souls?

Tags: beyond-two-souls

I am trying to determine if the choices you make have bearable effect on the story or if the game follows one narrative in a linear way despite of what the player decides.

Do choices only effect the episodes by themselves or are they reflected throughout the game? How close is it to Heavy Rain in terms of different possible endings?

I also have heard that the game features illusion of choices, e.g.

> with not being able to kill the father even though the option is offered.

Is this often the case or merely the exception?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but seeing as the episode selection being sporadic in the times of the events, I would assume player choice doesn't have that big of an impact... But I am just watching an LP and not playing it myself.

Comment: According to at least [IGN's review](http://ca.ign.com/articles/2013/10/08/beyond-two-souls-review), choices do not matter in any meaningful way beyond their episode and the "game" is more of a movie than anything. Given the game's non-linear telling and consequential disconnect between cause and effect, it's hard to imagine choices having any real impact unless the future somehow unintuitively changes the past.

Comment: @skovacs1 [violation of causality](http://hipercom.inria.fr/~jacquet/retro1/crazy-science-corner/causality.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes and no.

Yes in that the choices you make, and this will sound like buying into Cagedom, really do influence what that character becomes in your mind.  Even if you will see little actually change, the act of choosing (or experiencing the illusion of choice) really does have an impact.

No in that the game is pretty much a "Press a button to choose your ending" game and while you get a few alternate scenes at various points or miss content because of a failure on your part, it's all going on the same railroad tracks for the most part.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

Your choices in the game will affect your relationship with the other characters around you and it's even possible for characters to die if you fail at certain points.

The game has about six endings depending on the choices you made throughout the game.

Comment: Can you please elaborate how choices made during the course of the game affect the ending? From what I can see the ending is determined only by the choice that you make at the ending (beyond/life and who you want to live with).

Comment: I heard about 24 endings even. But they are probably all pretty similar.

Answer (score 2):

It's all about the journey, not about the destination.

Heavy Rain had pre-determined characters, you chose how the story unveiled.

Beyond: Two Souls has a pre-determined storyline, you choose how the characters develop.

Answer (score 0):

The game has 24 different endings. All the characters can die (including Jodie), and most of the choices you make have an effect on the relationships of all of the characters, and as someone mentioned already, the choices make the characters into more of how you envision them.

Answer (score -1):

No.

For instance, if you don't take ANY revenge whatsoever at the party and then are caught trying to escape Cole, Nathan will still give the same response of "Don't you remember what happened at Kirsten's birthday party? You know what Aiden can do, right? Right?!" That doesn't make sense if you didn't have your revenge.

Also, nothing is explained. If you take the choice and have a guard commit suicide and fail the mission at the fancy Shiek party, it won't affect anything later on.

Same with the amount of times you can reject Ryan. If you reject him at all times, the game still forces you to kiss him when you're about to destroy the condenser.

Also, the fact that you HAVE to save the little kid Salim, and you have to use his Dad to kill the soldiers, it doesn't give you any choice.

When those rapists ask if you wanna play pool with them and if you select "No", the game will still force you to go along with it.

Also, when Nathan asks you to talk to his dead wife and daughter, if you select "No", the game still forces you to go along with it.

Comment: Anonymous person submitting an edit: Please don't contradict the answer in an edit, instead leave a comment or submit your own answer. But since what you're trying to say was already said in a different answer, it's not useful to do it at all.